# storing xml attributes in php array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a xml file in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<adp_report name="Average Draft Position - Mixed 5x5" rundate="2013-01-29 17:22:10.0" begin="2013-01-26" end="2013-01-29" draftcount="126">
     <player id="500736" name="Mike Trout" position="OF" team="ANA" adp="1.66" early="1" late="4" selections="126" />
     <player id="291154" name="Ryan Braun" position="OF" team="MIL" adp="2.01" early="1" late="4" selections="126" />
     <player id="213968" name="Miguel Cabrera" position="3B" team="DET" adp="2.55" early="1" late="4" selections="126" />
</adp_report>
```

I need to load this into php where I will be able to access it by finding the name attribute and what the corresponding adp is. I am using it to perform some calculations and insert the results into a table that is being called from a MYSQL database. This is what I have so far:

```
$url = '...some url';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultbat, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
       echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
       ...print out some more player data from database...

       foreach($xml->player as $player)
            {
                $attr = $player->attributes();

                if($attr['name'] == $row['NAME']) //$row['NAME'] is the players name from my database
                {
                    $adp = (float) $attr['adp'];
                    $early = (int) $attr['early'];      

                    $stdev = -0.42+0.42*($adp-$early);
                    if($stdev<0)
                        $stdev = 1;
                    $chance =number_format(((1-NORMDIST($pickNumber,$adp,$stdev,TRUE))*100), 0);

                  echo "<td class='adp'>".$adp."</td>";
                  echo "<td class='chance'>".$chance."%</td>";
                  break;
                }
            }
}
```

This takes a while to process because I'm going through every row in my player database, then using `foreach` to look through the xml file and if I find a match I do the calculations. I have to imagine there is a more efficient way to go about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the right thing to do is to build a list of the player names form the XML and then query the database with an `IN` clause.  You're doing this in the reverse order, which requires querying unneeded data from the database and going through the entire table. That's not a scalable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XPath (see: [SimpleXMLElement::xpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) and [XPath documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath)). So, instead of your `foreach` loop, this:

```
$player = $xml->xpath('//player[@name="' . $row['NAME'] . '"]');
if (is_array($player) && count($player)) {
    $player = $player[0];
} else {
    continue; // not found
}
$attr = $player->attributes();
// and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd pre-process the XML file to an associative-array (user-id/user-name => properties);

```
$url = '...some url';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$players = array();

foreach($xml->player as $player) {
    $attr = $player->attributes();

    // cast the SimpleXMLElement to a string
    $username = (string) $attr['name'];
    $players[$username] = $attr;
}
```

Then retrieve the data from the database and match the results from XML

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultbat, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     if(!array_key_exists($row['NAME'], $players)) {
          // player was not found in the XML
          continue;
     }

     // get the player's properties by matching the 'name'
     $player_stats = $players[$row['NAME']];

     // here, process player_stats

}
```

However, your code assumes the player-name to be unique, it may be possible that multiple players share the same name (this problem was already present in your current code)

Comment: when I tested the first part of the code I get the following error: `Warning: Illegal offset type` for the `$players[$attr['name']] = $attr;` line. Am I missing something?

Comment: @rodzilla I suspect that $attr['name'] will produce a SimpleXMLelement object, not an actual string. This can be fixed by casting it to a string. I updated my code with this fix, haven't been able to test it though